# antlr text from matching rule in c#

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr3

In an Antlr 3 grammar, is it possible to print out the full text matching a rule in a grammar targeting c#? Something like below:

```
rule : FIRST SECOND
{ Console.WriteLine($rule.text); };//does not work. 

FIRST: 'first';

SECOND: 'second';
```

Comment: What about `$rule.text` (lowercase)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$rule.text` doesn't work (as @dana suggested), you might try `$rule.Text` or even `$rule.GetText()`.

If all fails, please tell us which version of the C# port you're using (and where it can be downloaded), then I (or someone else) can perhaps give it a try.